# HtmlHelper rendering Dictionary "keys" and "values" as attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, extension-methods, html-helper

If you feel you would like further background, I have previously posted and accepted this.
[Correctly making an ActionLink extension with htmlAttributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595334/correctly-making-an-actionlink-extension-with-htmlattributes)

This is a followup question. My problem is that I have two custom extentions where one calls the other. For some reason the htmlAttributes are rendering out like this.

```
<a Count="3" 
 Keys="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[System.String,System.Object]"
 Values="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[System.String,System.Object]"
 ...</a>
```

The above occurs when I call ActionImageLink2. The purpose of ActionImageLink2 is only to add attributes pairs. How can I make it that Keys and Values render correctly?

There is something up with the `HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes)`

### Here are my extension methods

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionImageLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string imageUrl, string altText, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, string _imageClass = "", object htmlAttributes = null)
        {

            var image = new TagBuilder("img");
            image.MergeAttribute("src", imageUrl);
            image.MergeAttribute("alt", altText);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_imageClass) == false) image.MergeAttribute("class", _imageClass);
            var link = helper.ActionLink("[replaceme]", routeValues, HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));

            return new MvcHtmlString(link.ToHtmlString().Replace("[replaceme]", image.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing)));
        }

        public static MvcHtmlString ActionImageLink2(this HtmlHelper helper, string imageUrl, string altText, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, string updateTarget, string _imageClass = "", object htmlAttributes = null)
        {
            RouteValueDictionary htmlAttr = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
            htmlAttr.Add("data-ajaxget-click", "");
            htmlAttr.Add("data-ajax-update", (updateTarget.Contains("#") ? updateTarget : "#" + updateTarget));

            return helper.ActionImageLink(imageUrl, altText, routeValues, _imageClass, htmlAttr);
        }
        public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string linkText, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, object htmlAttributes = null)
        {
            return helper.ActionLink(linkText, routeValues["Action"].ToString(), routeValues["Controller"].ToString(), routeValues, HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
        }
    }
```

### Here is my test View

Each ActionLink has a second line which is printing as ToHtmlString. The printscreen below shows the result.

```
@{RouteValueDictionary route = new RouteValueDictionary();
            route["Area"] = "";
            route["Controller"] = "Test";
            route["Action"] = "Test";
}

@Html.ActionLink("Html.ActionLink", route, new { style = "color: green" })
<br />
@Html.ActionLink("Html.ActionLink", route, new { style = "color: green" }).ToHtmlString()
<br />
<br />
@Html.ActionImageLink("https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/511438.png", "alt text", route, "image class", new { style = "background-color: orange" })
<br />
@Html.ActionImageLink("https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/511438.png", "alt text", route, "image class", new { style = "background-color: orange" }).ToHtmlString()
<br />
<br />
@Html.ActionImageLink2("https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/511438.png", "alt text", route, "partialDiv", "image class", new { style = "background-color: orange" })
<br />
@Html.ActionImageLink2("https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/511438.png", "alt text", route, "partialDiv", "image class", new { style = "background-color: orange" }).ToHtmlString()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionImageLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string imageUrl, string altText, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, string _imageClass = "", IDictionary<String, object> htmlAttributes = null) 
{
    //...functionality omitted...
    var link = helper.ActionLink("[replaceme]", routeValues, htmlAttributes);
    //... other ....
}

public static MvcHtmlString ActionImageLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string imageUrl, string altText, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, string _imageClass = "", object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    return helper.ActionImageLink(imageUrl, altText, routeValues, _imageClass, new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
}

public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string linkText, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    return helper.ActionLink(linkText, routeValues, HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
}

public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string linkText, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = null)
{
    return helper.ActionLink(linkText, routeValues["Action"].ToString(), routeValues["Controller"].ToString(), routeValues, htmlAttributes);
}
```

In a nutshell: overloading

Comment: For me, this was the "ah ha" moment: `new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes)`

Comment: ^^ just be sure to use `RouteValueDictionary` and not `object` for the RouteValues param as well else it will invoke the wrong extension method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I think lie in this line:

```
return helper.ActionImageLink(imageUrl, altText, routeValues, _imageClass, htmlAttr);
```

of your method `ActionImageLink2`. When you pass your htmlAttr variable to the method `ActionImageLink`, it is no more an anonymous type.

So you get the problem when in `ActionImageLink` you call again

```
HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes)
```

Have you try to check the type passing in before calling the above function?

Comment: Your assertion is correct.. if you call `HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes` twice it will add the various properties of the RouteValueDictionary as items in the dictionary. BTW, @MikeSW's usage of  `new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes)` doesnt read correctly, but it works!